# Is there any way to get the c# object/data on which NUnit test is failing?

Tags: automated-tests, nunit, testcase, playwright, nunit-3.0

I am writing unit tests for a complex application which has so many rules to be checked into a single flow by using **NUnit** and **Playwright** in .Net5. Actually the case is, to save the time for writing the test scripts for **Playwright** ***(front-end testing tool)***, we have used a library named **Bogus** to create dummy data dynamically based on the rules (because the test cases has numerous rules to be checked and it was much more difficult to write fresh data to every case). I am using Playwright script into the NUnit test and providing the data source by using `[TestCaseSource("MethodName")]` to provide dynamic data object for different cases.

Now, we are facing a problem that some of the tests cases get passed and some are failed and we are unable to identify that particularly which test case is causing the problem because the testcase data is being provided by the dynamic source and in that source the data is being generated by the Bogus library on the bases of the rules which we have generated. Plus, we cannot look at the tests for a long time that's why we have automated the process.

```
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource("GetDataToSubmit")]
        public async Task Test_SubmitAssignmentDynamicFlow(Assignment assignment)
        {
            using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false, 
                ...
            });
         ....

        private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetDataToSubmit()
        {
            //creating data for simple job
            var simpleAssignment = new DummyAssigmentGenerator()
                                            ....
                                            .Generate();
            yield return new TestCaseData(simpleAssignment);        
            ....
```

Now, my question is, **is there any way so that we can view that what were the actual values in the object in the failed case, when we see the whole report of the testcases**? So that we can come to know that which certain values are causing problems and eventually fixed those.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches...

1. Assuming that `DummyAssignmentGenerator` is your own class, override its `ToString()` method to display whatever you would like to see. That string will become part of the name of the test case generated, like...

   Test_SubmitAssignmentDynamicFlow(YOUR_STRING)
2. Apply a name to each `TestCaseData` item you yield using the `SetName()` fluent method. In that case, you are supplying the full display name of the test case, not just the part in parentheses. Use `{m}(YOUR_STRING)` in order to have it appear the same as in the first approach.

If you can use it, the first approach is clearly the simpler of the two.

Comment: I can use the first approach and it seems pretty well. But the problem here is that the Assignment class has too many attributes and it's kind of an effort required to write all of them in an overridden ToString method. Is there any easy way to do so too?

Comment: It's just programming. :-)

Comment: In my case, the second approach was more appropriate as I am generating dynamic data so it's difficult to overwrite the ToString Method on the bases numerous attributes. I have named each and every test case while providing the test case data and also logged the json object of the assignment by using Console.WriteLine() into the test case